# “In Betracht ziehen” vs. “in Erwägung ziehen”

Tags: difference

I have heard both structures (intended, I believe, to express: "to take something in consideration"). Do they mean the exact same thing? Are both used equally often?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general these two expressions mean the same. There is just a slight difference in common usage when talking about possibilities:

*In Betracht ziehen* adresses the *possibility* of an action.

> Man sollte in Betracht ziehen, dass man die Firma auflösen *kann*.
>   One should consider that it is possible to close the company. 
>  
>   Man sollte die Möglichkeit in Betracht ziehen, die Firma *aufzulösen*.
>   One should consider the possibility of closing the company.

*In Erwägung ziehen* is usually followed by the action itself:

> Man sollte in Erwägung ziehen, die Firma *aufzulösen*.
>   One should consider to close the company.

The remaining case

> Man sollte in Erwägung ziehen, dass man die Firma auflösen *kann*.

is not correct.

When talking about arguments, *in Betracht ziehen* is also more common.

So to conclude this: If you stick to *in Betracht ziehen*, you are on the safe side. But the differentiation of the two gives you the possibility to express more detailed.

I didn't find any exact rules on the usage, so I hope my examples explain my point.